# Is Microsoft moving to the Stack Overflow platform?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, microsoft

I recently heard that Microsoft is now planning to move all of their Q&A sites to the Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange platform (IIRC, it came up in a keynote by Scott Guthrie).

**UPDATE:**
Reference the ["Keynote: Getting Started with Windows Azure" video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/windowsazure/learn/Keynote-Getting-Started-with-Windows-Azure) starting about 1:30:41.

> "One of the things we're also doing, that we announced this past weekend is that we're actually moving to Stack Overflow as our primary way to get support forums and online help."

[image: Keynote of doom?]

Will this change have any impact on existing sites?

Is any deeper integration planned between SO and the new sites?

Does anyone have details on the timeline for the switch? Or which sites will be moved first?

Comment: Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: where did you got to know that,it may be a rumor, so tell the source of this information.

Comment: You didn't happen to hear this _last Sunday_, did you?

Comment: I can't find any evidence of this after an exhaustive search. When raising a topic like this, you really need to be able to let us 'hear' what you 'heard' from the same source you 'heard' it from.

Comment: I would guess you fell victim to not so funny April Fools' Day joke. (explaining [above comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128653/is-microsoft-moving-to-the-stack-overflow-platform#comment351293_128653) just in case)

Comment: 1:16:45 into this video: http://www.microsoft.com/belux/techdays/2012/SessionDetail.aspx?sessionId=266

Comment: As long as they don't get a dedicated subsite, I don't care.

Comment: Wow, so much hate! Here's a link from Dec 11, 2011: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/windowsazure/learn/Keynote-Getting-Started-with-Windows-Azure. The StackOverflow comments start at 1:30:41, including "One of the things we're also doing, that we announced this past weekend is that we're actually moving to StackOverflow as our primary way to get support forums and online help." After watching it a second time, maybe it's for Azure only?

Comment: @RickNZ, it's not "so much hate" (or at least not undeservedly so).  Without some way to trace your assertion, this post appeared to be classic FUD trolling.  And you must admit that what Scott said in both of his mentions of SO (yours and the one in my answer), is much less scary than the assumptions in this question.

Comment: Scott is a VP, and works on a wide range of products at MS, so when he says "we," my reaction was that he meant the company, not one group. In any case, I decided to ask him directly for an answer to this, rather than deal with the drama here. His response: "Right now we are mostly using this for Azure – although we do now link to StackOverflow as well from the www.asp.net web-site.  Right now we don't have plans to more products to 'officially' be supported on StackOverflow – but they are a great partner and one we want to support."

Comment: They did move to SO.  David Makogon and AvkashChaucan, the #1 and #3 answerers in the [azure] tag work for Microsoft.

Comment: A new step has been made: github has fallen. Crossing fingers so that SE does not follow the trend.

Answer (score 5):

At the [most recent big appearance by Scott Guthrie](http://www.annhoang.net/tag/devconnections/)  (*[DevConnections](http://www.devconnections.com/home.aspx)*, March 26 to March 29, 2012), he spoke about Windows Azure, and about open-sourcing ASP.NET.  He's not on record as having mentioned Stack Exchange.  No other Microsoft rep seemed to mention SE or SO either.

There is no record that I can find, so far, of Microsoft intending to adopt the Stack Exchange platform.  This would also seem unlikely given that Microsoft prefers to use its own stuff -- unless they plan on buying SE.  There's no evidence of that either.

[A Google search on `"Stack Overflow" "Microsoft" "customer" -site:stackoverflow.com` (and limited to the last month)](http://www.google.com/search?q=keynote%20by%20Scott%20Guthrie&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#hl=en&tbs=qdr:m&q=%22Stack%20Overflow%22%20%22Microsoft%22%20%22customer%22%20-site:stackoverflow.com%20&oq=%22Stack%20Overflow%22%20%22Microsoft%22%20%22customer%22%20-site:stackoverflow.com%20&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&psj=1&fp=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&cad=b) only returns 1,230 results... Paging through those, there is no mention of a planned integration of SE at Microsoft.

**Update:**
At 1:16:50 into [this TechDays, 2012 video](http://www.microsoft.com/belux/techdays/2012/SessionDetail.aspx?sessionId=266), Scott Guthrie says:

> "We provide both MSDN forums. Uh, we also, uh, now, uh, support Stack Overflow as kind of one of our default forum mechanisms. Uh, you can also get questions answered there. Uh, and we have a really active community both on Stack Overflow and MSDN you can take advantage of."

Which does not sound like any significant new development (except that SE is officially on some big radars). (Thanks [Uphill Luge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144883/uphill-luge), for the tip.)

Comment: `unless they plan on buying SE.` Thanks for the nightmares. :<

Comment: Here's a link to the video I saw: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/windowsazure/learn/Keynote-Getting-Started-with-Windows-Azure. His StackOverflow comments start at 1:30:41.